# How do I deal with cache and the browser back button in an ASP.NET app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, caching

How do I best handle when a user pushing back to a page that is cached with items in a `ASP.NET` app?

Could I handle the cache with by capturing it in the back buttons event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to perform state management in `ASP.NET` on page navigation. You can use client side state management techniques such as  `View` state , cookies and query string based on your requirement and amount of data you are going to cache.

Please refer below link for complete understanding of caching.

[ASP-NET-State-Management](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/331962/A-Beginner-s-Tutorial-on-ASP-NET-State-Management)